# How to checkout a single file or subtree from a git repository

Tags: git

Since source code repositories are databases it should be possible to get information out of them easily. The question is, what is the best way to extract a single file or sub-tree from a `Git` repository as a plain detached thing (file or sub-directory).

Perhaps something like this?

```
git extract --path /path/to/thing  path/to/repository
```

Comment: You have to pick some *commit* from which to extract the file or subtree. After doing so, you can use either `git restore` (only if you have the thing locally and want to extract the files into index and/or working tree) or `git archive` (can be used over the net, with some limitations, and is generally more flexible).